# handling action in view not router

Tags: ember.js

I have a view that has expandable/collapsable content that I'd like to be able to toggle by clicking the on the table row.   Before pre1.0, I had this in the template:

```
<tr {{action "expand"}}>
```

which was previously handled on my view:

```
App.ContentRowView = Em.View.extend({
   templateName: 'ember/templates/content/row',
   expand: function() {
      this.set('isExpanded', !this.get('isExpanded'));
   },
   isExpanded: false
});
```

However, after upgrading to pre1.0 the action is now fielded directly by the router.  This makes sense in a lot of situations, but in this case the expansion is really a view concern.   I've tried just replacing this with a click event handler without luck.

Is there a best practice on how to handle a view concern event like this with pre1.0?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Deprecated Answer**

---

Even if the answer of @outside2344 works, I think it's not exactly right.
Indeed `parentView` does not represent the view, but the parentView of its parentView.
Since 1.0-pre, views preserve their context, so in the template, `this` represents the parentView, `parentView` represents `parentView.parentView`, and `view` represents the current view. 
Here is a fiddle to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/cnmJa/

For me the answer is `{{action expand target="view"}}`

**EDIT** (answering to @Gal Ben-Haim)

Action helpers behave little different in a router-based application. Quote from the documentation:

> In Router-driven applications, if an action **is not intercepted by a view**, that event will bubble up to the Route in which that view was rendered. If that Route is a sub-route of another Route the transition will be sought there all the way up to the top-level Route definition, our über-container: root.
>
> This bubbling effect allows certain actions to remain private. If certain transitions should only be available for certain sub-sub-states, put the transition on the sub-state and you've achieved a type of scoping.

Basically, for me that means in **Router-driven apps** if you don't explicitly define a target in the action helper, it is sent to the router.

---

**Updated answer**

I think now the guides answer very well to this question. see http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_specifying-a-target

Comment: the router docs http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/#toc_navigation clearly speak about events being handled by views and a bubbling effect up to the router. I don't understand why this doesn't work and everything goes directly to the router, or the documents are wrong / outdated ?

Comment: I needed to quote my action for this to work: `{{action "expand" target="view"}}`

Comment: @pdenya You're right, because without the quotes it will try to find a property named `expand`, not the string `"expand"`.

Answer (score 1):

In pre1.0 you can make the view field the action by adding target="parentView" to the action:

```
{{action "expand" target="parentView"}}
```

Comment: You could also wrap the target (if you have multiple actions and/or bindings) to a single object/view using a `{{with}}` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Events doesn't bubble through the view-hierarchy by default. You can change this (though I can't say I'd recommend it):

```
(function() {
    Ember.View.reopen({
        // Let actions bubble to parentView by default.
        target: function() {
            return this.get('parentView');
        }.property('parentView')
    });
})();
```