# Editor form from button double click

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of records in a table.  I would like to display an editor form whenever a row is double-clicked.  It would be preferable, but not necessary, that the action is routed so that the form has a URL of something like /songs/edit/:song_id.  Most similar examples I've see wrap some text or button in #linkTo brackets, however I would like to do something similar from the View, so that I have an event of the form:

```
App.SongView = Em.View.extend({
    doubleClick: function(evt) {
        something here;    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using {{linkTo}} helper, you can use the {{action}} helper, and specify `target=view` (see [handling action in view not router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887836/handling-action-in-view-not-router)).

To handle changing the url, you can call `transitionTo` and give it the SongsEdit route, along with the argument.

template:

```
{{#each record in records}}
   <div class="record" {{action editForm record on="doubleClick" target="view"}}> ... </div>
   ...
{{/each}}
```

view:

```
editForm: function(record){
  // need to use the controller to call transitionToRoute
  this.get('controller').transitionToRoute("songsEdit", record);
}
```

Note that you don't actually have to handle this action in the view; it makes sense to handle this in the controller as well.

Alternatively, if you want to handle it with the built in `doubleClick` handler, you don't need to specify anything in the template, and you just have to make sure you have access to the individual record that you want to pass to `transitionTo`.

It could look something like:

```
doubleClick: function(e) {
  record = this.get('controller.content') // or however you're wrapping the underlying record
  this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('editRoute', record);
}
```

Your route would of course be responsible for displaying the actual edit form.

Comment: I used the latter technique and that did the trick :)  One follow up question: my route is named 'edit_route' rather than 'editRoute'.  I believed I was following the convention...is the lower camel case what I should actually be using?